# How to perform a serialized disk read for NTFS or ext2?

Tags: windows, linux, performance, io, filesystems

The background is to duplicate a large volume of files into another disk via program, so the basic idea is using serialized IO instead of random IO, that means I should sort the files based on their sector location, so, how could I sort them?

Comment: Are you looking for a programmic way to do this? If so, what language?

Comment: Are you trying to mirror a partition or just find a way to copy files fast?

Comment: You have to ensure the volume is mounted read-only, and you'll have to duplicate a lot of the filesystem functionality already existing in the kernel (e.g. using some `libext2` on Linux). Good luck! I'm not sure it is worth the effort!

Comment: Also, why do you think this approach is somehow "better" or "faster' than just copying the files one by one? You didn't actually say what your are trying to do or why you want to got about doing it this way. But it sounds like pre-mature optimization.

Comment: If you have several tasks (i.e. threads or processes) reading that filesystem, the kernel and the hardware will probably re-order the reads to minimize disk head motion.

Comment: Think about using rsync, if the process is interrupted rsync is a lot more efficient than serial copy.